# Why can't I access the value(s) of foreign key field(s) when using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a user table in my database that looks like this:

```
public class tblUser{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int? customer_id{ get; set; }
}
```

There is a foreign key on the `customer_id` column that links to the `tblCustomers` table where I can get extended information IF the user is in fact a customer.

When I was using Linq-to-SQL objects, I used to ensure that the user was linked to a customer by testing `customer_id.HasValue`, but having now changed to Entity Framework, I can't even see the `customer_id` property - am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Entity Data Model Wizard gives you the option **Include foreign key columns in the model**.
 This is off by default.

Comment: ...and the project needs to target .NET Framework 4.0 :) Thanks